# How to deal with the overwrite of visited anchors

Tags: css, colors, styles, visited

I'm trying to apply a specific color (green) on my sub-menu items when user is on the page of this specific item.

The problem is :

-All my menu items needs to be set to base color (ocher)

```
.header_menu {
text-decoration: none;
color: var(--lightocher);}
```

-So all anchors are set to same color for keeping them ocher even if visited.

```
.header_menu a:visited {
color: var(--lightocher);}
```

-So my green can't pass because he is overwritted by :visited color

```
.current_page_item, .current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent {
color: var(--green);}
```

How can I deal with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add also a more specific setting:

```
a.current-menu-parent:visited, a.current-menu-item:visited {
color: var(--green);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add !important to the rule even though its not very good to add it in specificity context.

```
    current-menu-parent:visited, current-menu-item:visited {
         color: var(--green) !important;
    }
```